# Which residue classes modulo $p$ have exactly one square root?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p>2$ be a prime. Which residue classes modulo $p$ have exactly one square root? Explain.

I am having trouble understand the question. What does it mean for a residue classes to have exactly one square root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only on residue class with exactly one square root: 0. All other classes have two square roots or none, as $\mathbf F_p$  is a field and if $b^2=a$, then also $(-b)^2=a$. Whether a residue class has a square root modulo $p$ can be determined with  Gauß's law of quadraric reciprocity.

Answer (score 2):

It ask for which residue classes $a+pZ$ there is a unique $b+pZ$ such that $(b+pZ)^2=a+pZ$.

$pZ$ is the only residue class with that property because suppose other $a+pZ$ had that property, then $(b+pZ)^2=a+pZ$ but also $(-b+pZ)^2=a+pZ$ and $b+pZ\neq -b+pZ$ because $p>2$.

Answer (score 1):

The residue classes modulo $p$ are the elements of the quotient ring (in this case it is even a field) $R=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. So a residue class has the form $c+p\mathbb Z$ which is normally just written as $\overline{c}$ or even $c$.

So a squareroot of $c$ is an element of $r\in R$ such that $r^2 \equiv c$. (That means that their residue modulo $p$ is equal.)

For example $p=5$ that means we consider $R=\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z = \{ \overline 0, \overline 1 , \ldots,\overline 6\}$ (Lets just ignore those bars, it is more convenient. Remember these are the residue classes, not the integers!)

Then $0^2 \equiv 0$,$1^2\equiv 1$,$2^2\equiv 4$,$3^2\equiv 2$ e.t.c